# How to remove a dataframe from an array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hello programmers around the world! I'm having a problem with removing dataframes from a list based on a condition

Here is what I tried:
1.Loop through every dataframe in the list.
2.Check the condition which is if a particular column is not present in the 
current dataframe
3.Remove dataframe

For some reason I get the following error:

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

```py
def removeCorruptData(array):
    for dataframe in array:
        if 'LoC' not in dataframe.columns:
            array.remove(dataframe);
```

I expected that to work but for some reason I get the following error:

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects.

Sadly,other than what is provided in the error message itself I haven't been able to find a solution to my problem. If anybody can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your Problem

You are trying to use `remove` on your list with a dataframe value.  Python is going to compare that dataframe with others to determine which one to remove.  This is not ideal.

#### What I'd do

This is going to mutate your existing list **rather** than returning a copy of your list that satisfies a condition.

Iterate through the list backwards while keeping track of where you are at.  You can use the `_i` index value to determine what you should `pop` off.  Because you are going backwards, you don't have to worry about the list's positions changing index values beneath you.

```
def removeCorruptData(array):
    n = len(array)
    for _i, d in enumerate(array[::-1], 1):
        if 'LoC' not in d:
            array.pop(n - _i);
```

Comment: Thanks just what I needed. Also note to everybody that the condition in the if statement is wrong but other than that the idea is there and the code works.

Comment: Thanks! Enjoy the rest of your day!

Comment: How do I do that?